# Cleanest iteration/functional application on Pandas Dataframe regardless of length

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I constantly struggle with cleanly iterating or applying a function to Pandas DataFrames of variable length. Specifically, a length 1 DataFrame slice (Pandas Series).

Simple example, a DataFrame and a function that acts on each row of it. The format of the dataframe is known/expected.

```
def stringify(row):
    return "-".join([row["y"], str(row["x"]), str(row["z"])])

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=[1,2,3],y=["foo","bar","bro"],z=[-99,1.04,213]))
Out[600]:
   x    y       z
0  1  foo  -99.00
1  2  bar    1.04
2  3  bro  213.00

df_slice = df.iloc[0]   # This is a Series
```

Usually, you can apply the function in one of the following ways:

```
stringy = df.apply(stringify,axis=1)
# or 
stringy = [stringify(row) for _,row in df.iterrows()]

Out[611]: ['foo-1--99.0', 'bar-2-1.04', 'bro-3-213.0']

## Error with same syntax if Series
stringy = df_slice.apply(stringify, axis=1)
```

If the dataframe is empty, or has only one entry, these methods no longer work. A Series does not have an `iterrows()` method and `apply` applies the function to each column (not rows).

Is there a cleaner built in method to iterate/apply functions to DataFrames of variable length? Otherwise you have to constantly write cumbersome logic.

```
if type(df) is pd.DataFrame:
    if len(df) == 0:
        return None
    else:
        return df.apply(stringify, axis=1)
elif type(df) is pd.Series:
    return stringify(df)
```

I realize there are methods to ensure you form length 1 DataFrames, but what I am asking is for a clean way to apply/iterate on the various pandas data structures when it could be like-formatted dataframes or series.

Comment: You could wrap things in try/except statements... which may be cleaner.

Comment: You should be aware that there is a difference between a DataFrame of length one and a Series. How are you ending up with Series where you expect one-row DataFrames?

Comment: [dinkelk] Try-excepts are fine, but they are just as cluttering to code.

Comment: [exp1orer] True, there is a difference. How about when you take a subset of a dataframe: `df.iloc[0]`, this gives you a series

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no generic way to write a function which will seemlessly handle both
DataFrames and Series. You would either need to use an `if-statement` to check
for type, or use `try..except` to handle exceptions.

Instead of doing either of those things, I think it is better to make sure you create the right type of object before calling `apply`.  For example, instead of using `df.iloc[0]` which returns a Series, use `df.iloc[:1]` to select a *DataFrame* of length 1. As long as you pass a slice *range* instead of a single value to `df.iloc`, you'll get back a DataFrame.

```
In [155]: df.iloc[0]
Out[155]: 
x      1
y    foo
z    -99
Name: 0, dtype: object

In [156]: df.iloc[:1]
Out[156]: 
   x    y   z
0  1  foo -99
```

Comment: @EdChum: Thanks for pointing that out. I made a small edit, `s/need to if/need to use/`, and quit the browser without checking the result. Apparently that can lead to duplicate posts. There is a [bug report here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265986/190597).